# Django: How does UpdateView change value of fields that is excluded in ModelForm?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

Here I have a ride-request class, and it has original passenger number and total passenger number. I allow user to change the value of original passenger number with ModelForm, and in UpdateView, I would like make total passenger number equals the original passenger number just received from ModelForm. Like this:
**ModelForm**:

```
class RequestOwnerForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = OwnerRequest
        fields = [

            'passenger_num',


        labels = {

            'passenger_num': 'How many passengers do you have?',

        }
```

and **UpdateView**:

```
class OwnerRequestEditView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.UpdateView):

    model = OwnerRequest
    template_name = 'ride/request_edit.html'
    form_class = RequestOwnerForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('ride:view_requests')

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        print("form is invalid")
        return HttpResponse("form is invalid.. this is just an HttpResponse object")

    def form_valid(self, form):
        pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        request = get_object_or_404(OwnerRequest, pk=pk)
        if request.status == 'open':
            request.passenger_num = form.cleaned_data['passenger_num']
            passenger_num = form.cleaned_data['passenger_num']
            request.total_passenger = passenger_num # I want total_passenger equals to passenger_num
            request.save()
            return super().form_valid(form)
```

But the fact is total_passenger does not change.

Could someone help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're updating the number, then calling super to save the form which overwrites the value you just saved with the original one.

I'm not sure why you want two fields with the same value, but you need to set this on the instance that has already been fetched by the view. You should let the view itself update the other fields and save.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    if request.status == 'open':
        form.instance.total_passenger = form.cleaned_data['passenger_num']
    return super().form_valid(form)
```